# Make a function that wait a parameter to change triggered by button

Tags: python, tkinter

The following is a program that does not make sense, but I want to do something similar in a larger code. One function is called and I want it to wait for a change in a parameter, where the change is triggered by a button. Running this code, when the OK button is pressed it doesn't allow for another button to be pressed and it freezes. Also before anything, I get the error: name 'boton' is assigned to before global declaration. Thanks for reading. Saludos.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
master = Tk()

def callback():
    w1['text']="this"
    while boton==0:
        time.sleep(1)
    w1['text']="and then this"

def switch():
    if boton==0:
        global boton
        boton=1
    if boton==1:
        global boton
        boton=0

boton=0
w1 = Label(master, text="")
w1.grid(row=0, column=0)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
b = Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)
b.grid(row=1, column=0)
b2 = Button(master, text="switch", command=switch)
b2.grid(row=1, column=1)

mainloop()
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `sleep()` in tkinter. It will freeze the program. 2. You wrote `boton` in the `switch()` function but because your function is treating it as a local variable then `boton==0` can't mean anything because locally (inside of the function) that variable has not been declared. Add this line to the top of `switch()`... `global boton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems and the two big ones are interrupting the Tkinter `mainloop()`.

When you press `OK` your program gets stuck in a while loop that can never be broken. Keep in mind Tkinter runs on a single thread and any time you create a loop then it blocks the `mainloop()` form working until that loop is broken. To get around something like this we can use the `after()` method to schedule and event to happen as part of the `mainloop()` instead. The second problem that is blocking the `mainloop()` is the `sleep()` method. This will have the same affect until the time is up.

We also need to make sure you are using if/else statements because your `Switch()` your `if` statements will always result in the 2nd text.

With that taken care of all we need to do now is a little cleanup.

Instead of doing `from Tkinter import *` we should do `import Tkinter as Tk`. This will keep us from overriding any methods from other imports or from variables we create.

You do not need to do `global` in each if statement. You just need it at the top of your function.

take a look at the below code.

```
import Tkinter as tk


master = tk.Tk()

def callback():
    global boton, w1
    w1.config(text="this")
    if boton == 0:
        master.after(1000, callback)
    else:
        w1.config(text="and then this")

def switch():
    global boton
    if boton==0:
        boton=1
    else:
        boton=0

boton=0
w1 = tk.Label(master, text="")
w1.grid(row=0, column=0)
e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Button(master, text="OK", command=callback).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(master, text="switch", command=switch).grid(row=1, column=1)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! Very clear why I was wrong and also provides code <3

Comment: @Palki  Glad to help.